# Selecting and Retrieving data point - Embedded Charts -VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table(Table1) which I have used to create a Scatter diagram("Chart Title") in the same sheet - Embedded chart. I want to select a data point and retrieve is values. I found the following online.

```
Dim myClassModule() As New EventClassModule

Sub InitializeChart()
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
    ReDim myClassModule(1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count)

    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Dim chtnum As Integer

    For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        chtnum = chtnum + 1
        Set myClassModule(chtnum).myChartClass = chtObj.Chart
    Next
  End If
 End Sub

 Sub ResetCharts()
 Dim chtnum As Integer

 For chtnum = 1 To UBound(myClassModule)
    Set myClassModule(chtnum).myChartClass = Nothing
 Next
 End Sub
```

This goes in the class module

```
  Public WithEvents myChartClass As Chart

  Private Sub myChartClass_Mousedown(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)

  Dim ElementID As Long, Arg1 As Long, Arg2 As Long
  Dim myX As Variant, myY As Double

  With ActiveChart
   .GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2

  If ElementID = xlSeries Or ElementID = xlDataLabel Then
   If Arg2 > 0 Then
      myX = WorksheetFunction.Index _
   (.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues, Arg2)

   myY = WorksheetFunction.Index _
   (.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Values, Arg2)
   MsgBox (Arg1 & Chr(10) & Arg2)
   End If
  End If
 End With
 End Sub
```

But the following line:

```
Dim myClassModule() As New EventClassModule
```

is causing an error:

> Used - defined type not defined  & Cannot perform requested operation

Any ideas why?

Comment: your class module must be named EventClassModule.
Go to vbe, on the top left in the project exlorer clic on the class,
and then on the property window, clic right to (name), and change the name to EventClassModule.

Comment: also, not sure why in the module they used `with activechart` , instead of the proper name `with myChartClass`

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using your code , i got this:

in the normal module (any name):

```
Option Explicit

Dim myClassModule() As New EventClassModule

Sub InitializeChart()
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim myClassModule(1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count)

        Dim chtObj As ChartObject
        Dim chtnum As Long 'Integer

        For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            chtnum = chtnum + 1
            Set myClassModule(chtnum).myChartClass = chtObj.Chart
        Next
    End If
End Sub

 Sub ResetCharts()
 'Dim chtnum As Long 'Integer

 If Not myClassModule Is Nothing Then
 '   For chtnum = 1 To ubound(myClassModule)
 '       Set myClassModule(chtnum).myChartClass = Nothing
 '   Next  
 Erase myClassModule
 End If

 End Sub



Sub entry()
Dim i&
Dim j&
For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 To 10
        Cells(i, j) = 100 * Rnd
    Next j
Next i

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(286, xl3DColumn).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$J$10")

End Sub
```

and in a class module (named EventClassModule):

```
Option Explicit


Public WithEvents myChartClass As Chart



Private Sub Class_Terminate()
Set myChartClass = Nothing
End Sub



Private Sub myChartClass_Mousedown(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)

Dim ElementID As Long, Arg1 As Long, Arg2 As Long
Dim myX As Variant, myY As Double

With myChartClass 'ActiveChart
    .GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2

    If ElementID = xlSeries Or ElementID = xlDataLabel Then
        If Arg2 > 0 Then
            myX = WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues, Arg2)

            myY = WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Values, Arg2)
            MsgBox (Arg1 & Chr(10) & Arg2)
        End If
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! But there seems to be one problem with it. If i click on a selected data i seem to be getting the wrong values. any ideas why ?

Comment: Never Mind it worked perfectly. Thank you very very much!