# add data to table by clicking point in scatter plot with excel

Tags: excel

I have a scatter plot with customer data. I want to make it so that when you click a dot in the scatter plot, that customers info is added to a list. Is there a way to do this in excel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695298/selecting-and-retrieving-data-point-embedded-charts-vba/44696809?noredirect=1#comment76378479_44696809

Comment: Yes, it's possible but you're gonna have to learn a shed load of VBA